# Repeat header on every page

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to repeat the header with the image (Report Header a) on every page
and display the page number at the bottom of every page. But I want (Report Header c) to come after the image.

[image]

Comment: Place it in the Page Header section

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b But I need the Report Header C to stay after the image.

Comment: So you mean the contents of report header c should also be in every page?

Comment: If not just duplicate whatever you have in report header at page header

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b No. The section with the image should be repeated every page. Followed by Report Header C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn both `Report Header A` and `Report Header C` into Page Headers, then use this formula in the suppression logic for `Report Header C`:

```
PageNumber <> 1
```

This makes the header with the image display on every page, but the header with `Date Prepared` will only show up on the first.

---

To display the Page Number on every page, move `Page N of M` to the Page Footer.

Comment: It works!!! But it adds blank space in the next page after the first page. Maybe because of the header that will disappear on the next page. How can I remove that?

Comment: Was able to make it work! Thanks for your answer!!! =) Just put the image group section into another page header and added you're suggestion code which is PageNumber <> 1 into suppression.

Answer (score 1):

The report header show only once per report... so you have to use the page header.

Right click on the page header section > insert > group > options > mark the checkbox "Repeat Group Header on Each Page" and voila.